# How to validate a string using regex in Java which will have 24 alphanumeric characters with a minimum of 8 alphabets and last 5 is numeric

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate a string which will have total 24 alphanumeric characters, a minimum of 8 alphabets and last 5 will be numeric. What will be the regex for it. I am new to regex. I am using this `[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,9}`, but it doesn't check the total length and doesn't ensure that last 5 are numeric and a min of 8 alphabets.

Comment: Q: Is a regex necessarily the best approach?

Comment: can you show us an example please?

Comment: for example 1B4YEM9P4KP186543 (Invalid), 1FA-CP45E-X-LF192944(Valid)

Comment: I am not sure whether regex will be best for this. You can suggest what you think best

Comment: what about the total should be 24 alphanumeric characters, but `1FA-CP45E-X-LF192944` is not contain 24 alphanumeric characters how did you explain this?

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way which can contain some regex :

```
if (str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").length() >= 8 && str.matches(".*\\d{5}")) {
    System.out.println("Valide");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not valid");
}
```

---

1. `str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").length() >= 8` replace all non alphabets then count the rest, if the rest equal or great then 8 then correct
2. `str.matches(".*\\d{5}")` mean if that the string should end with 5 degits

So for inputs like you provide in comment :

```
1B4YEM9P4KP186543      return "Not valid"
1FA-CP45E-X-LF192944   return "Valid"
```

---

**Note**

> I need to validate a string which will have total 24 alphanumeric
>   characters

to solve this you can add another condition `str.length() == 24` so your condition should be like this :

```
if (str.length() == 24
        && str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").length() >= 8
        && str.matches(".*\\d{5}")
        ) {
    System.out.println("Valide");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not valid");
}
```

---

**Note**

Like [@FedericoPiazza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516213/how-to-validate-a-string-using-regex-in-java-which-will-have-24-alphanumeric-cha/45516392?noredirect=1#comment77994207_45516392) mention in comment if you want to check non consecutive digits you can use `str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").lenght() >= 5` instead of `str.matches(".*\\d{5}")` so your condition should be :

```
if (str.length() == 24
        && str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").length() >= 8
        && str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").lenght() >= 5) {
    System.out.println("Valide");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not valid");
}
```

Comment: sorry i don't get you @FedericoPiazza

Comment: I was playing with the regex but the "non consecutive" requirement borks my regex. I added it just as a comment: `^(?=[\w-]{24})(?=.*[a-z]{8,}.*)(?=.*\d{5,}.*).{24}$`. **[Sample](https://regex101.com/r/jCHFm7/1)**. Btw, you have my vote

Comment: thank you @FedericoPiazza,  about the degits it is clear that the OP said  a minimum of 8 alphabets **and last 5 will be numeric** and last so i think it means it should end with 5 degits, i'm wrong?